# WiFi incorrect password returns true

Tags: android, android-wifi, android-connectivitymanager

I am trying to add the wifi network on my device like this

```
 public static boolean connectToWifi(String ssid, String password) {
    WifiConfiguration wifiConfig = new WifiConfiguration();

    wifiConfig.SSID = String.format("\"%s\"", ssid);
    wifiConfig.preSharedKey = String.format("\"%s\"", password);

    WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) getContext().getApplicationContext().getSystemService(WIFI_SERVICE);
    assert wifiManager != null;
    wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(true);
    int netId = wifiManager.addNetwork(wifiConfig);
    wifiManager.disconnect();
    wifiManager.enableNetwork(netId, true);

    return wifiManager.reconnect();

}
```

Whatever the password it returns true.

Then I checked the internet connection or not like this

```
 ConnectivityManager connectivity = (ConnectivityManager) getContext()
            .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo[] infos = connectivity.getAllNetworkInfo();
    for (int i = 0; i < infos.length; i++) {
        if (infos[i].getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED) {
            //   return true;  //<--  --  -- Connected
            Log.d("ConnectionString", "Connected");
        }
```

but it also returns true if I added the wrong password.
So can you please correct me on this issue.

Comment: `ConnectivityManager` monitors several network connections. Maybe you're connected via UMTS, Edge, ...?

Comment: I have added my wifi network and password other than that I didn't add anything. This is a audio device with with android OS

Also in the Log I printed the Connected WifiInfo SSID. It's showing the name which I added one only.

Comment: @Christopher This is return true after I called this connectToWifi() only. before that returning false.